# Determine if field is in a subset of values

Tags: splunk

I'm writing a query to determine what percentage of events are error events for a camera-based system.

To narrow logged events down to camera events, I have `event=camera*` in the initial query.

What I want to do next is treat the event as bad if it's in a subset, so I want something like:

```
event=camera* | eval bad_event=IF(event IN (camera-failed, camera-error, ...))
```

but I am not sure of the correct syntax for this in Splunk.

I tried `eval bad_event=IF(event=camera-failed OR event=camera-error)`, but got the message *Error in 'eval' command: The arguments to the 'if' function are invalid.*

How do I check if the event is in a subset of its possible values?

Answer (score 1):

You could do with with coalesce and case, or if and match ([documentation](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.2.5/SearchReference/CommonEvalFunctions#Comparison_and_Conditional_functions)):

Using case:

```
| eval event_type=coalesce(case(event=='camera-failed','bad',event=='camera-error','bad'), 'good')
```

Using match:

```
| eval event_type=if(match(event_type, 'camera-(failed|error)'),'bad', 'good')
```